# Vim: syntax files, load order is wrong

Tags: vim

I am stuck trying to figure out how I can get vim to load a specific syntax file for filetype `cpp`.

Running `:setlocal syntax?` yields `syntax=cpp` which makes me suspect that `cpp.vim` from lines 47-48 is loaded. The actual syntax file I want to use is the at the bottom of the `scriptnames` output. I know that it isn't being loaded because the colors are wrong.

```
  1: /etc/vimrc                                                      
  2: /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/archlinux.vim
  3: ~/.vimrc
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim80/ftoff.vim
  5: ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/autoload/vundle.vim
  6: ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/autoload/vundle/config.vim
  7: /usr/share/vim/vim80/filetype.vim
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin.vim
  9: /usr/share/vim/vim80/indent.vim
 10: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syntax.vim
 11: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/synload.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syncolor.vim
 13: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/plugin/NERD_tree.vim
 14: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/autoload/nerdtree.vim
 15: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/path.vim
 16: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/menu_controller.vim
 17: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/menu_item.vim
 18: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/key_map.vim
 19: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/bookmark.vim
 20: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/tree_file_node.vim
 21: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/tree_dir_node.vim
 22: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/opener.vim
 23: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/creator.vim
 24: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/flag_set.vim
 25: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/nerdtree.vim
 26: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/ui.vim
 27: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/event.vim
 28: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/notifier.vim
 29: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/autoload/nerdtree/ui_glue.vim
 30: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/nerdtree_plugin/exec_menuitem.vim
 31: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/nerdtree_plugin/fs_menu.vim
 32: ~/.vim/bundle/powerline/powerline/bindings/vim/plugin/powerline.vim
 33: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 34: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/gzip.vim
 35: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/logiPat.vim
 36: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/manpager.vim
 37: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/matchparen.vim
 38: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 39: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 40: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/spellfile.vim
 41: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 42: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tohtml.vim
 43: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 44: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
 45: /usr/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin/cpp.vim
 46: /usr/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin/c.vim
 47: /usr/share/vim/vim80/indent/cpp.vim
 48: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/cpp.vim
 49: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/c.vim
 50: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-cpp-enhanced-highlight/after/syntax/c.vim
 51: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-cpp-enhanced-highlight/after/syntax/cpp.vim
```

How do I change the order in which they are loaded? Or even force it to load only a specific `cpp.vim`? My `.vimrc` is available here https://gist.github.com/arynaq/1aa9011f636076e2d2766dff82e8b4af

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact you see it at the end of `:scriptnames` results means it **is** loaded.

To change the load order, you'd need to move the script from `syntax/after` to `syntax/`. But I'm quite certain this is not how the author expects it to work -- as the standard `syntax/c.vim` would clear the highlighting defined the new syntax plugin. BTW loading the standard syntax scripts for C and C++ is expected in your your case. Their presence, lines 48-49, is normal.

It seems that if you try to complete `:hi cpp` you should observe many `cppSTL` entries from this syntax plugin.

You'd need to be more specific about what you think is wrong. But honestly, this is quite certainly a question for the plugin author. Be sure you have correctly read the documentation and set the options to suit your expectations.

Comment: There are no specifics to running it, it is just a set of syntax files. I think you defined the problem better than in my OP, I think the standard syntax scripts overload my custom scripts. I know it isn't working because the scripts differ in color highlighting of eg functions.,

Comment: On the plugin repo (https://github.com/octol/vim-cpp-enhanced-highlight), I see the options documented. The source code, and the fact the syntax script is in `after/` subdirectory tell me you're in the nominal scenario. `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/c.vim` and `cpp.vim` shall be loaded first, then the new plugin adds complementary definitions. However, many are activated or deactivated depending on options.

Comment: BTW the standard syntax file for C and C++ cannot override the new ones as they are defined before. There sometimes some odd precedences rules when defining highlighting schemes. But then if there is something wrong, you'll have to see with the plugin maintainer. Anyway, I'm convinced you've installed/activated the plugin the way it's meant to be.